# getting the height/width of an image that does not have height/width set

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm working with a HTML page that has been created from a swf converter. The generated HTML uses SVG images to create the elements that match the layout of the swf.

I'm then trying to load in a image on top of these svg images, but unfortunately the svg images do not have the height and width set, so they look like this:

```
<div class="wlby_5">
    <!-- Start of symbol: element3 -->
    <img src="FlashTemplate_assets/svgblock_2.svg" class="wlby_4"></img>
    <!-- End of symbol: element3 -->
  </div>
```

When I append a image onto of this image, I can't get the original height and width to resize the image I'm loading so it resizes to match the original svg image. This is how I'm loading in the new image:

```
var imgWidth = $('div[class~="' + obj.name+ '"]').find('img').width()
var imgHeight = $('div[class~="' + obj.name+ '"]').find('img').height();


console.log("width of image", imgWidth);
console.log("height of image", imgHeight);
console.log( $('div[class~="' + obj.name+ '"]').find('img') );

$('div[class~="' + obj.name+ '"]').find('img').attr('src', obj.value);
$('div[class~="' + obj.name+ '"]').find('img').attr('width', imgWidth);
$('div[class~="' + obj.name+ '"]').find('img').attr('height', imgHeight);
```

So I'm trying to get the height and width of a image within the div layer, but these are not accessible, in the console they are both set as 0.

How can I access the height and width of the original svg image so I can apply it to the new image I'm loading?

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: I don't know what effect .svg has on things here, but for normal images, you can only obtain their height and width AFTER they have finished loading.  So, you have to set an `onload` handler and obtain the height and width when that fires.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to retrieve the height/width of an SVG image in these circumstances. Both methods work but I personally prefer the first.

**Option 1**

The `getBBox()` method of the SVGElement object can be used. This can retrieve the x and y offsets, as well as the width and height.

```
$('img').getBBox().width  
$('img').getBBox().height
```

**Option 2**

Alternatively, you can use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method like this:

```
$('img').getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

Comment: yes please, I tried the onload doesn't seem to work, well how I implemented it doesn't work.

Comment: @stevo okay give me a couple of mins

Comment: I've tried implementing the example you sent me, I seem to get a loop error, this is how I have implemented it `function loadImage(src){
 this.image = new Image();

 this.image.src = src;

 if(!this.image.complete && this.image.height==0){
  loadImage(src);
 }else{
  $('img').css({ display:block,
      width: this.image.width,
      height:this.image.height});

 }
}` then called this function like this `var img = $('div[class~="' + obj.name+ '"]').find('img'); loadImage(img);`

Comment: @stevo Sorry, I didn't make it clear. The `src` parameter is the source of the image. I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that, but still getting a error. The error msg is a repeated 'loadImage' text in red, nothing else.

Comment: @stevo Okay, give the new code a try. Can you also post up how you are calling the function? Make sure the source of the is absolute not relative, as in includes the URL! :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10221/discussion-between-stevo-and-ben-carey)